# Cocos 2D v1.0.1 : Crash at changing CCMenuItemImage normal image

Tags: objective-c, ipad, crash, cocos2d-iphone

I retrieve a crash log file, which, after XCode analysis on my archive show the problematic line of code :

```
Date/Time:       2012-12-08 23:48:08.930 +0100
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x31a4088f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3188b259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                  0x31a40789 +[NSException raise:format:] + 1
3   Foundation                      0x374c73a3 -[NSAssertionHandler     handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 91
4   Killer                          0x0017ed35 -[CCSprite initWithFile:] (CCSprite.m:201)
5   Killer                          0x0017e419 +[CCSprite spriteWithFile:] (CCSprite.m:93)
6   Killer                          0x00123101 -[Player makeZombie] (Player.m:1363)
7   Killer                          0x00105a51 -[PlayScene endOfKilling:] (PlayScene.m:1438)
```

Which clearly indicates the second of the two following lines is crashing:

```
NSLog(@"images %@ %@",self.zombieImage,self.zombieImageDown); 
[self.characterSprite setNormalImage:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:self.zombieImage]];
```

I know that the crash seem to happend when the user is touching the corresponding CCMeanuItemImage, is there a problem if the user is touching it, while we change the normal et selected images of it ? Is this the right manner to change its image (i do it several times during the game) ?

Thanks for your ideas

Answer (score 0):

Your crash is connected with touching your menu item only because of what you are doing in the method that is called on click your button.

From the crash report you can see the call stack that caused crash. It says that there was assertion in CCSprite class in the line 201 (as cocos2d is open source, you can check this line and see what kind of assertion was broken), that was called from your Player class in the method makeZombie in the line 1363 (are you sure you need so large class? I assume that you place too much logic into the single class).

So check the assertion line and check the line in your makeZombie method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, as said in my other answer in the other comment, i can't understand why my variable could be nil at that point, asserts are present each time it is assigned. Any idea to track this issue ? thanks

Comment: and thanks for your advice, my class is probably too large, even if corresponding to a real logical entity, i could probable slip some parts into smaller ones, although it has been done as much as possible :)

Answer (score 0):

The problematic call is initWithFile, since after this it gets called handlerFailureInMethod.
If the problem is initWithFile, for sure the file you are proving isn't available.
Check that self.zombieImage is a valid image filename.My guess is that zombie image isn't a filename (NSString), but an image (UIImage), so if that is the case, replace the image with it's filename.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seems the filename is just nil, but i set up asserts in very few places i assign this member, and i can't catch anything, it seems something is turning my variable to nil at some place, but i can't find how, could you advise how to track this event ? It seems the problem is not occuring each time

Comment: Since zombieImage is an ivar, you could observe that key path to see when it changes and it's set to nil.However if you don't track the bug post more code so that we see when the zombieImage becomes nil.